# How to approach VCs regarding employment

Tags: employment

I am a technical program manager specializing in mergers & acquisitions and instead of working for an Internet publishing company, I'd like to work on the venture capital (VC) side of the business. I have 20+ years digital experience and an education background in finance.

The problem is approaching VCs as it seems to be very insular with firms pulling from their own alma maters.

Here are some ideas I'd like feedback and bouncing ideas.

1. cold call (email?)
2. LinkedIn
3. conferences

Your thoughts and input on how to approach VCs would be welcome.

Comment: I made some edits to hopefully clarify you acronyms. If I made some mistakes, feel free to [edit your question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/51948/edit).

Comment: [Forget Cover Letters - Write A Pain Letter, Instead!](http://www.forbes.com/sites/lizryan/2014/10/12/forget-cover-letters-write-a-pain-letter-instead/) might be a good read.

Comment: I wonder if this might glean a better response on [startups.se]?

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of you first sentence.  You state you *are* a technical program manager specializing in M&A but then say you work for an internet publishing company?  Do you mean to say that you got a degree in M&A but you don't actually work in that field?  Or are you saying that the publishing company is large enough that they you are performing that job for them?

Comment: My education background is in Finance, I worked in accounting and auditing. I work for an internet publishing company where I am a technical PM specializing in M&A. I have 20+ years of experience in digital at various companies with various titles and duties.

Answer (score 3):

> How to approach VCs regarding employment

In my experience, working with/for VCs is very much dependent on your personal network.

Search long and hard to find a connection. You almost certainly know someone who knows someone who knows a VC or two. Use that connection.

Perhaps you have worked at a VC-backed startup before? Or perhaps in your mergers & acquisitions specialization work  you helped acquire a VC-backed startup? If so, consider all your coworkers at that company as folks who could potentially put you in contact with a VC or two. Start calling and asking.

Perhaps you know someone who knows a VC? If so, call and ask to be put in contacts.

Lots of M&A folks have a network that includes VCs or folks that have worked with VCs. Many have gone on to become VCs themselves. Call some of your personal connections and ask.

As with most employment activities, there's no magic here - just hard work. As with many job searches, your best friend is your personal network.